# JSON.parse gives error on gulp task

Tags: json, angularjs, gulp

I have this gulp task

```
gulp.task('replace', function () {  
  // Get the environment from the command line
  var env = args.env || 'localdev';

  // Read the settings from the right file
  var filename = env + '.json';
  console.log(filename)

  var settings = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config/' + filename, 'utf8'));

// Replace each placeholder with the correct value for the variable.  
  gulp.src('./js/constants.js')  
    .pipe(replace({
      patterns: [
        {
          match: 'apiUrl',
          replacement: settings.apiUrl
        }
      ]
    }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'));
});
```

I always get this error when i execute my code

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token /
  at Object.parse (native)
  at Gulp.<anonymous> (/home/k1ngsley/Projects/loanstreet-rea-app/gulpfile.js:86:23)
  at module.exports (/home/k1ngsley/Projects/loanstreet-rea-app/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
  at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/home/k1ngsley/Projects/loanstreet-rea-app/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
  at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/home/k1ngsley/Projects/loanstreet-rea-app/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
  at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/home/k1ngsley/Projects/loanstreet-rea-app/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
  at /usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:20
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
  at startup (node.js:119:16)
  at node.js:935:3
```

But if i remove the JSON.parse and just run

```
var settings = fs.readFileSync('./config/' + filename, 'utf8');
```

I get no error but the code is not parsed as json. What do i do? Why does JSON.parse not work in gulpfile.js

Any help appreciated

Comment: Isnt the error explicit enough ? parse error when parsing you config file, nope ? what is the content of the file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved this error by doing this

```
var setting = fs.readFileSync('./config/' + filename, 'utf8');
 var settings = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(setting));
```

Comment: I had a similar error with `SyntaxError: Unexpected token `. It was some sort of whitespace encoding shenanigan, so I used `JSON.stringify(setting.replace(/\s+/g, " "))` and it worked.

Comment: @Josh That was spot on my exact problem, how weird...can you explain why this happens?

Comment: There are whitespace characters that might not show up in your editor but aren't valid JSON. The `/\s+/g, " "` replacement converts them all to spaces (valid in JSON).